# How to sort array based on date in descending order if value exists in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I am trying to sort data based on descending order of `publishDate` but it's not working. In some array, `publishDate` is coming and in some array, it's not coming.

```
[
    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Brexit Delay",
        "publish": {

            "publishDate": "2019-8-30T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    },   

    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Example 3"
    },    

    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Example 2",
        "publish": {           
            "publishDate": "2019-6-30T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    },

    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Example 5"
    },    

    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Example 5",
        "publish": {           
            "publishDate": "2019-10-25T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    }
]
```

Js code:

```
data.sort(function(a, b){
    if("publish" in a && "publish" in b){
        return new Date(a.publish.publishDate) - new Date(b.publish.publishDate)
    }
} );
```

Comment: And how would you like to treat those objects where the `publishDate` is missing? Are they *later* that everything or *sooner*?

Comment: Additionally, you are checking `'publish' in a` while the key is called `publishDate` in the original object, so I guess it should be `'publishDate' in a`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek `publishDate` is a key of `publish`, so it doesn't matter. I'm assuming that if `publish` key exist then `publish.publishDate` will also have some date value.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek i want object without `publishDate` treat as sooner

Comment: @hussain.codes ah, sorry, you are right. I didn't see the `publish` key ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the property exists and based on this return order:

```
const myParseDate = date_string => {
    let [y,M,d,h,m,s] = date_string.split(/[- :T]/);
    return new Date(y,parseInt(M)-1,d,h,parseInt(m),s.replace('Z',''));
}

arr.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.publish  && b.publish) {
        return myParseDate(b.publish.publishDate) - myParseDate(a.publish.publishDate)
    }
    else if (a.hasOwnProperty("publish"))
        return -1;
    else if (b.hasOwnProperty("publish"))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
} );
```

An example:

```js
const arr = [
{
    "id": "brexit-delay",
    "title": "Brexit Delay",
    "publish": {
        "publishDate": "2019-8-30T12:25:47.938Z",
    }
},
{
    "id": "brexit-delay",
    "title": "Example 3"
},
{
    "id": "brexit-delay",
    "title": "Example 2",
    "publish": {
        "publishDate": "2019-6-30T12:25:47.938Z",
    }
},
{
    "id": "brexit-delay",
    "title": "Example 5"
},
{
    "id": "brexit-delay",
    "title": "Example 5",
    "publish": {
        "publishDate": "2019-10-25T12:25:47.938Z",
    }
}
]

const myParseDate = date_string => {
let [y,M,d,h,m,s] = date_string.split(/[- :T]/);
return new Date(y,parseInt(M)-1,d,h,parseInt(m),s.replace('Z',''));
}

arr.sort(function(a, b){    
if (a.publish  && b.publish)
    return myParseDate(b.publish.publishDate) - myParseDate(a.publish.publishDate)
else if (a.hasOwnProperty("publish"))
    return -1;
else if (b.hasOwnProperty("publish"))
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
} );

console.log(arr);
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want ascending order, then just change place of `a` and `b`:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.publish  && b.publish)
        return myParseDate(a.publish.publishDate) - myParseDate(b.publish.publishDate)
    else if (a.hasOwnProperty("publish"))
        return -1;
    else if (b.hasOwnProperty("publish"))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
} );
```

An example:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Brexit Delay",
        "publish": {
            "publishDate": "2019-8-30T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Example 3"
    },
    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Example 2",
        "publish": {
            "publishDate": "2019-6-30T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Example 5"
    },
    {
        "id": "brexit-delay",
        "title": "Example 5",
        "publish": {
            "publishDate": "2019-10-25T12:25:47.938Z",
        }
    }
]

const myParseDate = date_string => {
    let [y,M,d,h,m,s] = date_string.split(/[- :T]/);
    return  new Date(y,parseInt(M)-1,d,h,parseInt(m),s.replace('Z',''));
}

arr.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.publish  && b.publish)
        return myParseDate(a.publish.publishDate) - myParseDate(b.publish.publishDate)
    else if (a.hasOwnProperty("publish"))
        return -1;
    else if (b.hasOwnProperty("publish"))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
} );

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: According to output of your code this `Example 2` is coming on 2nd position but it should be on first position.

Comment: @Addy `Example2` has `2019-6-30T12:25:47.938Z`, however `Brexit Delay` is `2019-8-30T12:25:47.938Z` and it is descending order

Comment: What changes, i need to made if i want `asc` order

Comment: your code working fine with js execution. But i am trying to use code in node js i get issue with array which don't have date.

Comment: @Addy as a good practice at stackoverflow, it is better to have one question per post. Could you create a new post with error?

Answer (score 0):

a sort function must return a number. you have an if statement inside your sort compare function with and comparator, so if some object does not have publish date, the compare function does not return anything, you might try to place more if's

```
a.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.publish && b.publish) {
        return //compare condition
    } else if (a.publish && !b.publish) {
        return //compare condition
    } else if (!a.publish && b.publish) {
        return //compare condition
    } else {
        return //compare condition
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code to this:

```
data.sort(function(a, b){
    if("publish" in a && "publish" in b){
        return new Date(a.publish.publishDate.replace("T", " ") - new Date(b.publish.publishDate.replace("T", " "))
    }
} );
```

new Date("2019-10-25T12:25:47.938Z") just returns the string "Invalid Date" unless you replace the "T"